# Readonly textarea and IE9 Scrollbars

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

I'm having troubles with textareas readonly attribute. I'm using JQuery to set the attribute, like this :

```
$("#mytextarea").prop("readonly", true);
```

The CSS :

```
textarea { width: 400px; height: 400px; }
textarea[readonly] { overflow: auto; }
```

The HTML :

```
<textarea id="mytextarea">Lorem ipsum [...] ament.</textarea>
```

In Internet Explorer 9, the scrollbars are not showned so users can't read the overflow content. The behavior with all others majors browsers is correct : the field is not editable but users can freely scroll inside it.

How to fix this?

Comment: I don't know what version of jQuery you are using, but as of version 1.6, the appropriate way to handle properties is with [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/): `$("#mytextarea").prop("readonly", true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

> **visible** The overflow is not clipped. It renders outside the element's
>   box. This is default
>
> **hidden** The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be
>   invisible
>
> **scroll** The overflow is clipped, but a scroll-bar is added to see the
>   rest of the content
>
> **auto** If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar **should be added** to see the
>   rest of the content    inherit    Specifies that the value of the overflow
>   property should be inherited from the parent element

Try out "scroll" as the value of overflow property like this :

Change : `overflow: auto;` to `overflow: scroll;`

Since it does what you not want only in IE9 and if you want to keep auto for other broswer. Create two CSS files and use this code inside your HTML :

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9.css">
<![endif]-->
```

and put `overflow: scroll;` inside the ie9.css and `overflow: auto;` inside your regular CSS.

**EDIT: Scott** suggested, I do too, try to read this link http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ ... about how to incorporate multiple css for each browser. It's a good idea and a good way to reduce HTTP request.

Comment: At the expense of another HttpRequest.  You could use [Paul Irish's method](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) to add conditional classes to the html tag which allows you target whatever version of IE you need to handle, in one stylesheet, saving you that HttpRequest.

Answer (score 2):

Change `overflow: auto` to `overflow: scroll`.